# Using active class in Razor Syntax if statemements

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a form where it renders partial views based on the step that you are on.  I want to create a wizard type navigation at the top.  How can I go about having an active class based on what partial view is rendered at the time?

I have my wizard

```
<div class="container wizard">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified thumbnail">
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Step 1</h4>
                    <p class="list-group-item-text">Select a Loan Type</p>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="active">
                <a href="#">
                    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading active-heading">Step 2</h4>
                    <p class="list-group-item-text">Enter Personal Information</p>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="disabled">
                <a href="#">
                    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Step 3</h4>
                    <p class="list-group-item-text">Third step description</p>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="disabled">
                <a href="#">
                    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Step 3</h4>
                    <p class="list-group-item-text">Third step description</p>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried doing

```
@if (@html.partialview("index") {
     class="active";
}
```

That didn't seem to work.

UPDATE:

I've used an HTML Helper to use the active class, but it things I'm on index view because of the ajax calls.

```
public static string IsActive(this HtmlHelper html,
                              string control,
                              string action)
    {
        var routeData = html.ViewContext.RouteData;

        var routeAction = (string)routeData.Values["action"];
        var routeControl = (string)routeData.Values["controller"];

        // both must match
        var returnActive = control == routeControl &&
                           action == routeAction;

        return returnActive ? "active" : "";
    }
```

Comment: looks like `js` work, why are you trying to use `razor`?

Comment: Is the html provided included in a shared view used by all the steps?  Are you using ajax to fresh only part of the page with the "index" partial view?

Comment: The HTML provided is rendered into _layout.cshtml so yes it is on all steps.  Yes, ajax is being used to fresh only part of the page within the index partialview.

Comment: Are you essentially attempting to change the class on each li item as it is clicked?  In other words, change the clicked one to "active" and the one that was previously clicked to "disabled"?  If so then, @teovankot is correct that needs to be done in javascript.  You can call a javascript function from the oncomplete or onsuccess result of the ajax update in razor.

Comment: Do you want to add the class name as Active to the partial view container div right ?

Comment: It would be on each <li> item depending on what partialview i'm on